# XSLT ordering nodes based on external condition check

Tags: xml, xslt, nodes

My xml looks like as shown below. In this, few itemName values doesn't exist in the database. So I'll check each of these 'itemName' values and if any value doesn't exist in the database, the enclosing 'order' node should be displayed at the end. 
It means all the 'order' elements whose all the 'itemName' values exist in the database have to be displayed in sequence first and all the remaining 'order' elements for which at least one 'itemName' value doesn't exist in the database has to be moved to the end.

```
<record>
<purchases>
    <purchase id="purchase_1">
        <customer>
            <FirstName>first</FirstName>
            <LastName>last</LastName>
        </customer>
    </purchase>
</purchases>
<orders>
    <order id="order_1">
            <item id="1111">
                <itemName>ABC</itemName>
            </item>
    </order>
    <order id="order_2">
            <item id="1111">
                <itemName>ABC</itemName>
            </item>
    </order>
    <order id="order_3">
            <item id="4444">
                <itemName>MNO</itemName>
            </item>
        </order>
</orders>
```

I can take care of this condition check on database from my java based application. I am trying to code XSL by starting with identity transform and then using apply-templates, but I couldn't understand how to execute the database condition while calling apply-templates. I tried something like as shown below which is in addition to the default identity template:

```
<xsl:template match="/record/orders">
<xsl:apply-templates select="order[process all order elements whose condition check returns true]" />
<xsl:apply-templates select="order[process all order elements whose condition check returns false]" />
```

Assuming that the itemName 'ABC' doesn't exist in the database, the expected output is:

```
<record>
<purchases>
    <purchase id="purchase_1">
        <customer>
            <FirstName>first</FirstName>
            <LastName>last</LastName>
        </customer>
    </purchase>
</purchases>
<orders>
    <order id="order_3">
            <item id="4444">
                <itemName>MNO</itemName>
            </item>
    </order>
    <order id="order_1">
            <item id="1111">
                <itemName>ABC</itemName>
            </item>
    </order>
    <order id="order_2">
            <item id="1111">
                <itemName>ABC</itemName>
            </item>
    </order>
</orders>
```

Can somebody please provide a clue on how to proceed further? Thanks a lot for your time.

For better understanding of the problem, the code which I've tried so far is given below. This code will push only one 'order' element whose itemName value is not present in database to the end of the file. I am looking for all such 'order' elements to be pushed to the end. The template 'item-check-db' executes an SQL and returns either 'yes' or 'no' depending on whether the item is present in DB or not. I use xsl:import statement to import all my list of templates.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common" version="1.0">

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="exists" />
    <xsl:variable name="orderPos">
        <xsl:for-each select="/record/orders/order">
            <xsl:variable name="exists">
                <xsl:call-template name="item-check-db">
                    <xsl:with-param name="item" select="item/itemName" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:if test="$exists = 'no'">
                <xsl:value-of select="position()" />
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="string-length($orderPos) = 0">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="alterOrders" select="node() | @*">
                <xsl:with-param name="lastOrderPos" select="$orderPos" />
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="node() | @*" mode="alterOrders">
    <xsl:param name="lastOrderPos" />
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="alterOrders" select="node() | @*">
            <xsl:with-param name="lastOrderPos" select="$lastOrderPos" />
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="/record/orders" mode="alterOrders">
    <xsl:param name="lastOrderPos" />
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="alterOrders" select="order[not(position()=$lastOrderPos)]" />
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="alterOrders" select="order[position()=$lastOrderPos]" />
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="alterOrders" select="@*" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

I am looking for XSLT 1.0 solution.

*For some reason, the last line of my code or xml fragment is not getting displayed here.

Comment: "*Assuming that the itemName 'ABC' doesn't exist in the database*" How would this assumption be passed to the XSLT?

Comment: @michael.hor257k say I got another xsl template which takes the itemName value as input and does whatever processing is required (like executing an SQL or any other necessary operations) and returns 'true' or 'false'.

Comment: I am afraid that's not clear enough. Why don't you show us that template (or a simplified example thereof)? -- Also indicate XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Comment: A note regarding "say": IMHO, this is a crucial part of the process; if your actual mechanism is not what you ask us to suppose, this is going to turn out a huge waste of time.

Comment: For better understanding of the problem, I've added the code that I tried with so far in the question and provided some explanation. Please go through it and let me know if you need any further details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First and foremost:

You cannot sort nodes by non-existing properties. Properties that need to be ascertained by calling a template are (at the time of the sort) non-existing. The same thing applies to your attempt to differentiate between the nodes by using a *predicate*.

Therefore, you will need to process the nodes in two stages: first, attach an attribute to each one, then sort the resulting node-set by that attribute.

Unfortunately, you did not show us the template that checks the existence of an item. For the following example, I'll make one up:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">

<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="orders">
    <!-- first pass -->
    <xsl:variable name="orders">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="order" mode="first-pass"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <!-- output -->
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="exsl:node-set($orders)/order">
            <xsl:sort select="@exists" data-type="text" order="descending"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="order" mode="first-pass">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:attribute name="exists">
            <xsl:call-template name="item-check-db">
                <xsl:with-param name="item" select="item/itemName" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="item-check-db">
    <xsl:param name="item"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$item!='ABC'"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When the above is applied to the following **test input**:

```
<record>
    <purchases>
        <purchase id="purchase_1">
            <customer>
                <FirstName>first</FirstName>
                <LastName>last</LastName>
            </customer>
        </purchase>
    </purchases>
    <orders>
        <order id="order_1">
                <item id="111">
                    <itemName>ABC</itemName>
                </item>
        </order>
        <order id="order_2">
                <item id="222">
                    <itemName>DEF</itemName>
                </item>
        </order>
        <order id="order_3">
                <item id="111">
                    <itemName>ABC</itemName>
                </item>
            </order>
    </orders>
</record>
```

the **result** will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<record>
   <purchases>
      <purchase id="purchase_1">
         <customer>
            <FirstName>first</FirstName>
            <LastName>last</LastName>
         </customer>
      </purchase>
   </purchases>
   <orders>
      <order id="order_2" exists="true">
         <item id="222">
            <itemName>DEF</itemName>
         </item>
      </order>
      <order id="order_1" exists="false">
         <item id="111">
            <itemName>ABC</itemName>
         </item>
      </order>
      <order id="order_3" exists="false">
         <item id="111">
            <itemName>ABC</itemName>
         </item>
      </order>
   </orders>
</record>
```

Comment: @micheal.hor257k processing nodes in two stages is what I need here. Also by adding an additional template `<xsl:template match="order/@exists" />` I will get rid of this intermediate attribute in the final output. Thanks a lot for your guidance micheal.hor257k